# What step am I missing when setting up my JPA web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I have been trying to set up a JPA web application but I am running into some problems, I have made previous JPA applications that worked but I cant remember what step I am missing. The following is steps I take when setting up my application, I am using Netbeans.

1.right click on libraries and add library EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) which adds eclipselink.jar, 
javax.persistence_2.1.0v201304241213.jar,
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar

2. run the following sql file:

DROP DATABASE if exists TempDB;

```
CREATE DATABASE TempDB;

USE TempDB;

CREATE TABLE user(
name    VARCHAR(50),
password VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

3.Generate entity classes from database

[Generate Entity class settings 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8lwN.png)

[Generate Entity class settings 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh0c1.png)

User.java file:

```
package jpa.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.name == null && other.name != null) || (this.name != null && !this.name.equals(other.name))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jpa.test.User[ name=" + name + " ]";
    }

}
```

Persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebApplication3PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/TempDB</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[Persistence.xml settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBoS6.png)

test.java:

```
package jpa.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebApplication3PU"); 
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        User user = new User("John","Doe");
        try 
        {
            trans.begin();
            em.persist(user);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }    
}
```

Error Stack trace:

```
run:
Nov 13, 2017 7:36:04 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
[EL Info]: 2017-11-13 19:36:04.847--ServerSession(364597300)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:242)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:378)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:625)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2017-11-13 19:37:29.687--ServerSession(364597300)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/TempDB].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/TempDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at jpa.test.test.main(test.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:368)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
    ... 26 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/TempDB].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/TempDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at jpa.test.test.main(test.java:22)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/TempDB].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/TempDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/TempDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:494)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:625)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:480)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:242)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:378)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:331)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:368)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
    ... 26 more
C:\Users\buttons\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 27 seconds)
```

Like I said above I have other JPA applications from a long time ago that work, I have pointed those applications to the TempDB connection and it works but if I use a different sql file and generate new entities in those old applications I get the above error.

Comment: Why dont you simply try spring-boot!!

Comment: Did you create the datasource "jdbc/TempDB" in your server?  The error says it can't find this datasource when it attempts to look it up, so you need to add it for it to find it.

Comment: Hi, I don't think JNDI is finding jdbc/TempDB.
In order for the JNDI to work you need to check if the "jdbc/TempDB" is referenced and configured correctly in all persistence.xml and server.xml. You need to have it there listed as Resource and also have jdbc/TempDB as ResourceLink.